# Как создать файловую систему FAT16 в своей ОС?

Tags: c, ассемблер, ос

Я пишу свою операционную систему на C и NASM, столкнулся с проблемой при создании файловой системы, я не знаю с чего начать её делать, материалов по этому в интернете практически нету. Подскажите кто может/знает как сделать ФС, скиньте какие-то материалы или примеры кода по этому.

P.S Я использую загрузчик GRUB

Comment: Для начала проще вообще этим не заморачиваться, форматировать диск сторонними утилитами.

Comment: @insolor лично я не уверен, что под словом «создать» автор имел в виду именно форматирование

Comment: @andreymal ну это у автора уточнять. "Создать" - это именно форматировать. Если автор что-то другое имел в виду, то это не проблема прочтения вопроса, это проблема его формулировки.

Comment: @insolor я имел ввиду написание драйвера для своей операционной системы

Comment: Навскидку - посмотрите исходники FreeDOS. По идее, где-то тут: https://github.com/FDOS/kernel/blob/master/kernel/fatfs.c . Или исходники какой-нибудь другой небольшой ОС. А так вопрос слишком большой для stackoverflow.

Comment: В интернете полно информации. Начните с https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table (внизу там куча ссылок на источники с разной степенью подробности)

Comment: Устройство HDD не такое сложное. Микропрограммы БИОС могут форматировать сектора, от 256 байт до 64к (по моему). В 0 секторе загрузчик, далее FAT (2 таблицы) с разметкой папок, файлов, в каких секторах они находятся. Ну и как вы понимаете 16 это разрядность FAT (File Area Table), где максимальное число секторов, дорожек, не более 65535. Ну и как пишут в комментах, по FAT16, FAT32 есть куча документации в инете. Делайте сразу FAT32, потом переделывать придется все равно ;)

Comment: Лучше не копировать а делать свою FAT. Это похоже на malloc, только на HDD ;) И указатели хранятся в секторах (таблицах) указывая на сектор, где хранится файл (его данные), с указателем на следующий сектор, до конца файла :) Это как память, с ячейками от 256 до 64к, что задается форматированием.

Comment: @FrancNet, если уж делать свою, то вряд ли стоит копировать структуру FAT (списки на диске(!) и вся дурь с ограничениями на имена файлов). Лучше для основы взять идеи из extFS

Comment: @avp Я понимаю, но подскажите с чего начать её делать, можете скинуть примеры кода или что-то такое?

Comment: @Kerman, начать надо с рисования ручкой на бумаге структур данных, которые описывают носитель (его физические характеристики, т.е. сектора, дорожки, цилиндры) и служебные данные о размещении каталогов и файлов на нем. Рисуете и смотрите, как наиболее разумно можно разместить эти логические блоки данных на физическом уровне. Что касается примеров -- почитайте, скажем --  https://parallel.uran.ru/node/382 (то что рядом, тоже можно -))